# extracting data from google sheets with regextract

Tags: regex

Here is am example of data which is getting auto updated in google sheet
data sample - Furnished room: 2

I just want to extract number after Furnished room:, but I am facing problem with SPACE before number,

I've tried using `(\d)`, but its extracting data after SPACE and Number.

But data is somtimes before SPACE or after SPACE

Comment: add an example for the text that you wants to match and what you have tried

Comment: `(\d)` just matches a single digit. I assume it will match the first one encountered.